# Why are my DLL's being overwritten and what can I do to stop it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, bin

this is an area I have limited knowledge on, so if I'm missing any key information please ask questions and I will try to provide it. Up until recently I had been able to copy DLL's from the bin folder in one project to the bin folder in another project, but all of a sudden when I do a build in the second project, the DLL's are being overwritten.

This question is about 2 ASP.NET projects I'm working with, Project A does the heavy lifting and contains the data access layer, business logic layer etc. it is used by other projects. Project B sits on top as an abstract layer to handle requests from the UI to only deliver the stuff that's needed to the front end. When I make changes to Project A, such as updating a model, I would copy the DLL's from the Project A bin folder to the Project B folder and do a re-build and Project B would be able to see the updated model.

However now when I follow the same process, upon rebuilding Project B, the DLL's are being overwritten.

The bin file is not part of the source code, when deploying to the test or prod environments the updates are wrapped up in a nuget package, so the deployment process looks like this:

1. Build Project A on test server
2. In Project B get the updated nuget package that is created during the build
3. Deploy Project B to the test server

I've read through Stack Overflow and I've seen mentions to the Global Access Cache, but when I look at the logs for this by running gacutil -l in the developer command prompt, I can't see anything with any specific references to Project A.

When I inspect the DLL's using JetBrains dotPeek I can see that the DLL from Project A does contain the updated model.

Any and all suggestions welcome for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be manually copying dlls - if you've got a dependency them either add a `ProjectReference` or a `PackageReference` in `ProjectB.csproj` specifying the dependency and let the build handle copying dlls for you

Comment: @rbennett485 Project B does have a project reference to Project A in the Dependencies/Assemblies folder. I've tried deleting it and re-adding it, but when I do the build it still overwrites the DLL to an older version.

Comment: Sounds like you've got something really funky going on then, I'm afraid it's probably not possible to guess what that might be from the info we've got. If you can share project files then that may help